# Are docker volumes better option for write heavy operations than binding directories directly?

Tags: linux, performance, docker, docker-volume

Reading through docker documentation I found this passage (located [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#suitability-for-your-workload)):

> **Block-level storage drivers such as `devicemapper`, `btrfs`, and `zfs` perform better for write-heavy workloads (though not as well as Docker
>   volumes).**

So does this mean that one should always use docker volumes when expecting lot's of persistent writing?

Answer (score 1):

The container-local filesystem never stores persistent data, so you don't have a choice but to mount something into the container if you want data to live on after the container exits.  The "block-level storage drivers" you quote discuss particular install-time options for how images and containers are stored, and aren't related to any particular volume or bind-mount implementation.

As far as performance goes, my general expectation is that the latency of disk I/O will far outweigh any overhead of any particular implementation.  Without benchmarking any particular implementation, on a native Linux host, I would expect a named volume, a bind-mount, and writes to the container filesystem to be more or less similar.

From a programming point of view, you will probably get better long-term performance improvement from figuring out how to have fewer disk accesses (for example, by grouping together related database requests into a single transaction) than by trying to optimize the Docker-level storage.

The one prominent exception to this is that [bind mounts on MacOS are known to be very slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap) and you should avoid them if your workload involves substantial disk access.  (This includes both reading and writing, and includes some interpreted languages that want to read in every possible source file at startup time.)  If you're managing something like database storage where you can't usefully directly access the files anyways, use a named volume.  For your application code, `COPY` it into an image in a `Dockerfile` and do not overwrite it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

> should always use docker volumes when expecting lot's of persistent writing?

It depends.

Yes you want some kind of external to the container storage for any persistent data since data written inside the container is lost when that container is removed.

Whether that should be a host bind or named volume depends on how you need to manage that data. A host volume is a bind mount to the host filesystem. It gives you direct access to that data, but that direct access also comes with uid/gid permission issues and losses the initialization feature of named volumes.

Named volumes with all the defaults is just a bind mount to a folder under /var/lib/docker, so performance would be the same as a host volume of the underlying filesystem is the same. That said the named volume can be configured to mount just about anything you can do with the mount command.

Since each of these options can have varying underlying filesystem, and the performance difference comes from that underlying filesystem choice, there's no way to answer this in any generic sense. Hence, it depends.